# Изменить синтаксис, сохранить отступы

Tags: php

```
if($news) {
          $Sitemap .="        <priority>{$v[1]}</priority>\n";
          $Sitemap .="        <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>\n";
          $Sitemap .="        <lastmod>".date('Y-m-d', $r['time_upd'])."</lastmod>\n"; 
}
```

Возможно так

```
if($news)
    $Sitemap .="        <priority>{$v[1]}</priority>\n        <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>\n        <lastmod>".date('Y-m-d', $r['time_upd'])."</lastmod>\n";
```

Вопрос в том, возможно ли как во втором случаи, только каждый раз с новой строчки и сохранить отступ в начале чтобы на выходе читабельный вид имел ситемап.

Единственное, вложенность условий может быть 5-10 и тд. Можно сделать так

```
       if($news)
         $Sitemap .="        <priority>{$v[1]}</priority>
<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
<lastmod>".date('Y-m-d', $r['time_upd'])."</lastmod>\n";
```

Тогда в php будет плохой вид для чтения кода...

Comment: читай документацию про HEREDOC и NOWDOC

Comment: пробелы и отступы вашем ситемапе - лишний и ненужный объем. Хотите чтобы красиво выглядело при чтении - открываете в редакторе/просмотрщике xml  а не в блокноте, или браузеру корректные заголовки формата отдавайте, чтобы он красиво показал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы уже знакомы с composer'ом и ООП, то вы можете использовать [какую-нибудь](https://packagist.org/packages/samdark/sitemap) готовую библиотеку для генерации сайтмапа. Проблема отступов в этом случае не актуальна, вы просто заменяете xml на вызовы соответствующих методов.

Такой подход позволит решить задачу максимально быстро (в плане затрат на кодирование), но лишит вас удовольствия разобраться с тем, что умеет php и с какими трудностями сталкиваются крутые разработчики типа автора либы.

Answer (score 0):

Писать XML в PHP-файле — не самая лучшая идея. Гораздо удобнее писать PHP-вставки в XML-файле.

```
    <priority><?= htmlspecialchars($priority) ?></priority>
    <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
    <lastmod><?= htmlspecialchars($lastmod) ?></lastmod>
```

Положите такой код в отдельный файл `sitemap.pxml` и подключите его через [require](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.require.php).

Генерация XML/HTML/XHTML часто вызывает трудности у новичков, поэтому я написал небольшую [статью](https://egorbanin.github.io/junior/templates/) на эту тему. Почитайте.

Comment: он xml пишет вообще

Comment: My bad. Тогда `sitemap.pxml` :-) Разница-то не большая.

Comment: разница будет большая, если не генерить верстку руками, а сформировать именно XML соответствующими средствами, и сделать его экспорт в текст.

Comment: @teran согласен. Напишите ответ с использованием соответствующих средств, если вам не сложно.